# React shows another page and then the Homepage, whe navigating to Homepage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to React and I am using the Traversy crash course and the extra video about the react router 6+.

My Routes are like

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom'

return (
  <div className="container">
    <Router>        
      <Header
        title='sikyona'
        onAdd={()=> setShowAddtask(!showAddTask)}
        showAdd={showAddTask}
      />
      <Routes>
        <Route 
          path='/'  
          element={
            <>
              {showAddTask && <AddTask onAdd={addTask} />}
              {tasks.length > 0
                ? <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} />
                :<p>add tasks</p>  
              }
            </>
          } 
        />
        <Route path='/about' element={<About/>} />
      </Routes>
      <Footer />    
    </Router>  
  </div>
);
```

The problem is that when I navigate to the homepage http://localhost:3000/ I first see the About page for a second, and then the homepage (Route path='/'...)

I have `"react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",`

What is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: I don't see overt issue with the code. Could you try creating a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Didn't found any issue as well. Try creating a codesandbox demo of your whole code

Comment: @DrewReese please take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fermat-p0f365?file=/src/App.js:1458-1465) . Thanks

Comment: @AmjedAli please take a look at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-fermat-p0f365?file=/src/App.js:1458-1465) . Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue ***isn't*** that the "About" page or `About` component is being rendered when the app is loading or navigating to `"/"` for the first time. It's that the app ***is actually*** on `"/"` and there's no `tasks` to display just yet and the UI is rendering the container, `Header`, the `Route` for `path="/"` with the "add tasks" text, and the `Footer` which renders a link to `"/about"`.

[image: Home page view with no tasks]

Contrast this rendered UI with the *actual* `"/about"` path and `About` component.

[image]

Perhaps the UI/UX is fine for you with regards to this behavior and understanding what exactly is being rendered when, and for what reason. If on the other hand you ***don't*** want to see any of the UI until data has been loaded you can tweak the code to render  nothing or some loading indicator while the tasks are fetched.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const [showAddTask, setShowAddtask] = useState(false);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(); // <-- initially undefined

  useEffect(() => {
    const getTasks = async () => {
      try {
        const tasks = await fetchTasks();
        setTasks(tasks); // <-- defined and populated
      } catch(error) {
        // log errors, display message, etc... or ignore
        setTasks([]); // <-- defined and empty
      }
    };
    getTasks();
  }, []);

  ...

  if (!tasks) {
    return null; // <-- return null or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Router>
        <Header
          title="hello"
          onAdd={() => setShowAddtask(show => !show)}
          showAdd={showAddTask}
        />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <>
                {showAddTask && <AddTask onAdd={addTask} />}
                {tasks.length ? (
                  <Tasks tasks={tasks} onDelete={deleteTask} />
                ) : (
                  <p>add tasks</p>
                )}
              </>
            }
          />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/task-details/:id" element={<TaskDetails />} />
        </Routes>
        <Footer />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to put your `<Route path='/' />` last in the list.

Comment: Just FYI, route paths are now *always* exactly matched in RRDv6, so route order is irrelevant.

Comment: Good to know, haven't used React router for a while but that's an error i got before.

Comment: Route order and path specificity mattered in RRDv4/5 where the `Switch` component rendered the first matching `Route` or `Redirect` component. RRDv5 uses a [route ranking system](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#ranking-routes) now to select the best match.